# Prime Vue Tooltip is shown under other components

Tags: vue.js

I have added a Prime Vue v-tooltip.top to a different divs.
The Problem is that the tooltips are shown under others divs. I tried to change the css with :deep, but it doesn't seem to work. How can I change the z-index or there is another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Since it is not inside the component the css cannot be modificed inside the scoped style tag. With :deep it doesn't work, but using the nomal class name(p-tooltip) does